# Flash banner overlapping other code

Tags: css, flash, html

When flash banners from thirdparty are displayed they are overlapping my code:

[image]

test URL is: http://test.otwierac.pl/ (refresh page many times and you will see)

Code is:

```
<div style="width:100%">
<div id="banner">

<script>
<!--
var d = new Date();
r = escape(d.getTime()*Math.random());
document.writeln('<script src="http://tracking.novem.pl/rotator/CD31115/59&js=1&r='+r+'&keyword="><\/script>');
//-->
</script><div id='beacon_1' style='position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; visibility: hidden;'><img src='http://test.otwierac.pl/reklamy/www/delivery/lg.php?bannerid=1&amp;campaignid=1&amp;zoneid=0&amp;loc=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.test.otwierac.pl%2F&amp;referer=http%3A%2F%2Ftest.otwierac.pl%2F&amp;cb=6d0002d6e4' width='0' height='0' alt='' style='width: 0px; height: 0px;' /></div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
#banner
{
    margin-top:10px;
    width:950px;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align:center;
}
```

How to fix this ? Banners should be centered and not overlapping my text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDITED:

Try:

```
#banner {
    height: 315px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 950px;
}
```

Comment: I'm talking about the large banner in the middle of the screen.

Comment: See my edit... BTW, your markup is quite messy, try fix it or you will have problems with future updates.

Answer (score 1):

There's a flash parameter 
wmode: opaque

Should do the trick

**EDIT**

From the [adobe website](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/flash-object-embed-tag-attributes.html#main_Optional_attributes):
**opaque** - The SWF content is layered together with other HTML elements on the page. The SWF file is opaque and hides everything layered behind it on the page. This option reduces playback performance compared to wmode=window or wmode=direct.

Comment: Yeah, noticed it afterwards. But just to be clear, my answer is valid for this problem. Or you ask a modification to the third-party or you wrap that js script in another function to add the wmode parameter if possible.

Comment: No additional API of those third-party banners perhaps?